# How to add 2 JFrames to a single JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have 2 Frames that represent a bargraph.  The valueFrame is input textboxes for integers.  The barFrame is the bargraphs corresponding to the valueFrame.

I want to take these 2 seperate frames and put them into 1 JPanel side by side. So when the program runs, I see 1 JPanel with 2 frames inside.  When I try to add the frames, I get an IllegalArgumentException.  Can anyone show me how I could do this correctly?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArrayList<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>();

  data.add(new Double(33.0));
  data.add(new Double(44.0));
  data.add(new Double(22.0));
  data.add(new Double(22.0));

 Model model = new Model(data);

 View1 valueFrame = new View1(model);

  View2 barFrame = new View2(model);

  model.attach(barFrame);

  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
  mainPanel.setSize(600,400);
  mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  mainPanel.add(valueFrame,BorderLayout.WEST);//IllegalArgumentException
  mainPanel.add(barFrame,BorderLayout.EAST);//IllegalArgumentException
  mainPanel.setVisible(true);
}

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a     container
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:488)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1089)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:971)
at Ales6_7.Ales6_7.main(Ales6_7.java:43)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: @nachokk would JInternalFrame just replace JPanel?

Comment: Add two different layouts to one JFrame for the result you desire. - not two views. This is uneccessary.

Comment: @user3345200 No, JInternalFrame replace the JFrames..  you add InternalFrame to a DesktopPane , read my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a `JFrame` to a `JPanel` message is self-explanatory what you can do is take a look to `JInternalFrame`.

> With the JInternalFrame class you can display a JFrame-like window
>   within another window. Usually, you add internal frames to a desktop
>   pane. The desktop pane, in turn, might be used as the content pane of
>   a JFrame. The desktop pane is an instance of JDesktopPane, which is a
>   subclass of JLayeredPane that has added API for managing multiple
>   overlapping internal frames.

Read more: [How to use InternalFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want two frames side-by-side add two layouts to your `JFrame`(Looks like your JFrame is already using `BorderLayout` so technically you can add these two new layouts to your `JFrame` `BorderLayout` on respective east and west if you want to get the look you are currently trying to achieve.)

More about layouts http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html